# initialize a structure table in C

Tags: c

I have structure table that I want to initialize in the beginning of my program

```C
typedef struct MyStructT{
    int     Output; 
    int     Input1;
    int     Input2;

}; 
int n=100;
MyStructT Table[n] = ?? ;
```

How do I do it?

Comment: Does it have to be a variable length array? If you can use a static or a global array (i.e. define it as at the compilation unit level, with a fixed `#define` length instead of `n`), it will be initialized to `0`. Otherwise just set it manually to `0` before using it. Note that local VLA variables are usually placed on the stack, so in embedded environments you might want to be careful how much you will allocate.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this using array initialisation since `n` is not known at compile time; i.e. you have a *variable length array*.

One way is to loop over each element of the `struct` array, and initialise the members manually. It'll pop out nicely in a few lines.

Alternatively, given that the C standard guarantees contiguity of the `struct` elements, and `memset` to 0 is a well-defined way of initialising a C `struct`, you *could* `memset` the entire array:

```
memset (Table, 0, n * sizeof(struct MyStructT));
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you have:

```
int n = 100;
MyStructT Table[n];
```

you have a VLA — variable length array.  You cannot initialize VLAs.  Period.  You have to write code to set them to an initial value, somehow.

The standard (ISO/IEC 9899:2011 — C11) says in §6.7.9 **Initialization**:

> ¶3 The type of the entity to be initialized shall be an array of unknown size or a complete
>   object type that is not a variable length array type.

Note that changing `n` to `const int n = 100;` doesn't help in C (though it would in C++ — but C++ doesn't support VLAs anyway, despite GCC allowing them).

If the requirement is to set the elements to all bytes zero, then you could write:

```
memset(Table, '\0', sizeof(Table));
```

which will do the job.  Note that the value of `sizeof(Table)` is evaluated at runtime because `Table` is a VLA.

Alternatively, if you don't really need a VLA, change the array bound to an `enum` or `#define` constant and then you can initialize the array using the normal techniques.

Comment: And if I dont initialize my table is there any bug risk ?

Comment: No bugs unless you're naughty and read the elements before writing to them.

Comment: `sizeof(Table)` = flashy = upovote. I chickened out with that notation.